Monomorphism from $G$ to $S(G)$ through right-translation
Let $G$ be a Group. Define right-translation as
$$
\tau_a : G \rightarrow G, \quad g \mapsto ga.
$$
I want to show that
$$
f : G \rightarrow S(G), \quad a \mapsto \tau_a
$$
is a monomorphism. ($S(G)$ being the set of all bijective functions from $G$ to itself)
The only part I'm struggling with is showing $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$. Here's what I've done so far: ($x,y,g \in G$)
$$
\begin{align}
(f(x) \circ f(y))(g) &= (\tau_x \circ \tau_y)(g) \\
&= \tau_x (\tau_y (g)) \\
&= \tau_x (gy) \\
&= gyx \\
&= \tau_{yx} (g) \\
&= f(yx)(g)
\end{align}
$$
And clearly $f(xy) \neq f(yx)$, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong?

It is an anti-morphism. But you can define $(\tau_x\circ \tau_y)(g)=\tau_y(\tau_x(g))$ to obtain a homomorphism.

It depends on how you define  the product of symmetry group elements. Whether you get a monomorphism or an anti-monomorphis. Some people define $\sigma\cdot\tau$ as applying $\sigma$ firs then $\tau,$ others define $\sigma\cdot\tau$ as function composition, so $\tau$ is applied first, then $\sigma.$

Another idea is to consider here left-tranlsation instead. Then everything works with your definitions.

@DietrichBurde Thank you for your answer, the book I'm reading used left-translation as an example, constructing the monomorphism using right-translation was one of the exercises. I didn't even think to redefine the operation on S(G), it makes complete sense now!

Try with $g\mapsto ga^{-1}$.

Think about it: the function symbol $\tau_a(g)$ is on the left, but the multiplication $ga$ is on the right. So there's no hope for being a homomorphism: $\tau_b \tau_a(g) = g(ab) = \tau_{ab}(g)$. At least, not without doing some kind of "left-right" dance. Some people will use post-fix function notation for this purpose: $(g)\tau_a = ga$ and then it works, $(g)\tau_a \tau_b = g_{ab}=(g)\tau_{ab}$.
